# залить фигуру картинкой java

Tags: java, swing, png

Задача учебная на java. В ней есть объект, который выглядит как круг и двигается за целью (типа игра). Не получается сделать, чтобы круг был заполнен картинкой .png 
Цветом залить получается, но надо, чтобы картинкой. 
Делаю вот так:

```
   `BufferedImage colobok;
    try {
        colobok = ImageIO.read(new File("colobok.png"));
        g.setPaint(new TexturePaint(colobok, new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,44,44)));
        fillOval(g, robotCenterX, robotCenterY, 20, 20);

    }catch (IOException ex) {}
    //fillOval(g, robotCenterX, robotCenterY, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    drawOval(g, robotCenterX, robotCenterY, 20, 20);`
```

но получается, что он не заполняется картинкой, а делает "замостить" и в итоге отображается некорректно, так как при движении почти никогда рисунка не видно. 
Подскажите, что я делаю не так? и как это можно исправить?

Comment: почему вам не подходит какой-нибудь вариант [`drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver))?

Comment: мне нужно просто чтобы у меня был именно круг, заполненный картинкой, а не картинка, так как именно на этой логике построена вся работа проекта, а это очень много кода, часть из которого нельзя редактировать

Comment: а можно посмотреть на рабочий код? ссылку на гитхаб или добавьте минимальный но запускабельный тестовый код к вопросу. есть предположение, что рисунка не видно по причине производительности кода, но не понятно, ваш пример просто ужат для наглядности или же вы действительно читаете файл на каждое событие отрисовки?